# How to find id of selected array in arraylist in android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I have one array list, contains list of countries, next i selected particular student that is in string array. so how to find that selected string array of respective array list ids.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String log_email, log_pass, selectedcon = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        s.add("Nepal");
        s.add("Korea");
        s.add("Sri Lanka");
        s.add("India");
        s.add("Pakistan");
        s.add("China");
        s.add("Australia");
        s.add("Bhutan");

        String s1 = "Australia, Nepal, India, Korea";

        String selectedHobbies[] = s1.split(",");
        Log.d("TAG", "ddddd--"  + "----"
                + selectedHobbies.length);
        if (selectedHobbies.length != 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; i < selectedHobbies.length; j++) {

                    String t = selectedHobbies[j];
                    if (Arrays.asList(s.get(i)).contains(t)) {

                        selectedcon = selectedcon + i + ",";
                        Log.d("TAG", "Testing--" + i + "----"
                                + selectedcon);
                    }
                    // int match=false;
                }
            }

        }
        Log.d("TAG", "Selected--ddddddddd---" + selectedcon);
    }


}
```

I want of find ids of selected countries of array list.

Comment: you want index of selected country.??

Comment: ...and where is your any list view?

Comment: Yes, I want to index.

Comment: can you please ellaborate a little

Comment: There is misunderstood in problem but I think you want check if your s1 can be found in s, right?

Comment: how to find ids of string array s2 with respective array list s.

Comment: please check main answer

Comment: and my solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        s.add("Nepal");
        s.add("Korea");
        s.add("Sri Lanka");
        s.add("India");
        s.add("Pakistan");
        s.add("China");
        s.add("Australia");
        s.add("Bhutan");

        String s1 = "Australia, Nepal, India, Korea";
        String selectedHobbies[] = s1.split(",");

        for (int i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<selectedHobbies.length;j++) {
                if (s.get(i).contains(selectedHobbies[j])) {
                    Log.d("xxx", "found");
                    Log.d("xxx", "s index " + i);
                    Log.d("xxx", "hobbies index " + j);
                }
            }
        }
```

Corrected.